# SYNTAX ERROR : Insert SQL VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am a very beginner in coding, changing career and doing self learning+enrolled to a self funded course to get into programming. I posted some similar question earlier but now I have more bigger issue in my code!
It was partially working until I mess it up :(.. I have a form which the user will fill then store it into Microsoft Access database, when it was working the first detailed user entered was perfectly stored into my table but second deatiled it skipped the first field (firstname in my case) and stored the firstname to Surname(my second field) basically every time it was skiping one field and starting from the following field ( Hope I am clear!) .. Now that I changed my code, It keeps giving me Syntax error and I checked different tutorials and different syntax ( they all use different syntax) but this error is VERY persistant!

Please, help me.. below is mycode

Imports System.Data.OleDb

```
Public Class FirstCode
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Dim provider As String
    Dim dataFile As String
    Dim connString As String
    Dim myConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    End Sub

    Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles save.Click
        provider = "Provider= Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.15.0;Data Source = "
        dataFile = "C:\Users\Data.accdb"
        connString = provider & dataFile
        myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
        myConnection.Open()
        Dim str As String

        str = "INSERT INTO RegisterList (FirstName,Surname,Email,Location,ZipCode,Num,[Password]) + VALUES (@FirstName,@Surname,@Email,@Location,@ZipCode,@Num,@Pass)"

        str = " Insert into RegisterList (FirstName) Values(@FirstName)"
        str = " Insert into RegisterList (Surname) Values(@Surname)"
        str = " Insert into RegisterList (Email) Values(@Email)"
        str = " Insert into RegisterList (Location) Values(@Location)"
        str = " Insert into RegisterList (ZipCode) Values(@ZipCode)"
        str = " Insert into RegisterList (Num) Values(@Num)"
        str = " Insert into RegisterList (Password) Values(@Pass)"

        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", TextBox2.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Surname", TextBox3.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", TextBox3.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Location", DropDownList1.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CourtName", TextBox4.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Homecare", TextBox5.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pass", TextBox6.Text)

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        myConnection.Close()

    End Sub

    Protected Sub Button1_Click1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: you replace your SQL string over and over.  the long one has an errant `+` in it.  all those tags cannot apply.  If it is VB.NET it cant be VBA and asp classic seems unlikely

Comment: yeah I am using vb.net and the forms asp.net, I took off the + but I still have Insert Syntax error

Comment: Did you also get rid the of the 7 `str= "INSERT ...` statements which follow?  DId you fix change the @homecare and @Pass parameters?  You should [Edit] your post with the current actual code

Comment: Thanks your comment was helpful :D

Answer (score 0):

1. This looks like some flavor of VB, not VBScript. Asp-classic uses either VBScript or JavaScript, not VB.
2. Think about what's happening here:

   ```
   ...
   str = " Insert into RegisterList (FirstName) Values(@FirstName)"  
   str = " Insert into RegisterList (Surname) Values(@Surname)"  
   ...
   ```

   What is the value of `str` after the second line? So when your code gets to

   ```
   Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
   ```

   what is the value of `str`? (The above is definitely VB, not VBScript. VBScript can't do `dim x As`, nevermind `New`.)
3. Why is there a + sign in the following line? (I've broken it into multiple lines for readability.)

   ```
   str = "INSERT INTO RegisterList" _
     & " (FirstName,Surname,Email,Location,ZipCode,Num,[Password])" _
     & " + VALUES (@FirstName,@Surname,@Email,@Location,@ZipCode,@Num,@Pass)"
     '   ^ that plus sign - why is it there?
   ```

Comment: but even if I take the + sign, i recieve an error in the line cmd.executeNonQuery().... Error: An exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

Comment: @Vicky: unfortunately, it's been many years since I've had to work with VB, and I never did any sort of database access with VB, so I don't know where the problem lies. Do you have direct access to the database? Can you try out the SQL statement there? Also, have you tried writing out the SQL statement before executing it?

Comment: Wait a sec: I just noticed that you're listing FirstName, Surname, Email, Location, ZipCode, Num, and Pass as your VALUE parameters, but when you're actually adding parameters, you're doing FirstName, Surname, Email, Location, CourtName, Homecare, and Pass. So you're not adding ZipCode and Num, but you are adding the nonexistent parameters CourtName and Homecare.

Comment: thanks very much for taking your time, I appreciate it :D

Answer (score -1):

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles save.Click
provider = "Provider= Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.15.0;Data Source = "
dataFile = "C:\Users\Data.accdb"
connString = provider & dataFile
myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
myConnection.Open()
Dim str As String

str = "INSERT INTO RegisterList (FirstName,Surname,Email,Location,ZipCode,Num,[Password]) VALUES(@FirstName,@Surname,@Email,@Location,@ZipCode,@Num,@Pass)"

Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", TextBox2.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Surname", TextBox3.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", TextBox3.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Location", DropDownList1.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ZipCode", TextBox4.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Num", TextBox5.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pass", TextBox6.Text)


cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
myConnection.Close()




End Sub
```

Comment: As I explained above, If I took away th +, I get thos error.. An exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.